# How to change dataypes when encoding JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

Dealing with a semi JSON API of google that returns everything as a string - even numeric elements.

```
// [
    {
    "id": "22144"
    ,"t" : "AAPL"
    ,"e" : "NASDAQ"
    ,"l" : "100.75"
    ,"l_fix" : "100.75"
    ,"l_cur" : "100.75"
    ,"s": "0"
    ,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT"
    ,"lt" : "Sep 26, 4:00PM EDT"
    ,"lt_dts" : "2014-09-26T16:00:01Z"
    ,"c" : "+2.88"
    ,"c_fix" : "2.88"
    ,"cp" : "2.94"
    ,"cp_fix" : "2.94"
    ,"ccol" : "chg"
    ,"pcls_fix" : "97.87"
    }
    ]
```

When encoding that response to dict:

```
uquotes = json.loads(status.text[3:])

print uquotes
```

I get all elements of the incoming JSON structure as strings:

```
[{u'c': u'+2.88', u'ccol': u'chg', u'e': u'NASDAQ', u'ltt': u'4:00PM EDT', u'cp_fix': u'2.94', u'c_fix': u'2.88', u'l': u'100.75', u's': u'0', u'lt': u'Sep 26, 4:00PM EDT', u'pcls_fix': u'97.87', u't': u'AAPL', u'lt_dts': u'2014-09-26T16:00:01Z', u'l_fix': u'100.75', u'cp': u'2.94', u'id': u'22144', u'l_cur': u'100.75'}]
```

Two parts to the question:

1. How do I encode numeric values as such and not strings with something like:

   ```
   try:
       d[t.tag] = int(text)
   except ValueError:
       try:
           d[t.tag] = float(text)
       except ValueError:
           d[t.tag] = text
   ```

   Try Integer, back down to Float and default to text as a last resort.
2. How do I turn all keys into (ascii)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to catch `ValueError` looks fine to me, but you may as well make everything float; there are no large numbers in there that wouldn't fit in a float precision.

Note that Google most likely uses strings because these are monetary values, and the `float()` type may not make sense here unless you need to perform arithmetic on a large number of these.

It doesn't matter that your strings are `unicode` values, but you can always encode them to ASCII explicitly:

```
try:
    d[t.tag] = float(text)
except ValueError:
    d[t.tag] = text.encode('ASCII')
```

Python will implicitly encode to ASCII when you mix `unicode` with `str` values, and you can use the `str` version of any of the keys interchangeably.

If you want to insist on still supporting integers, test the string with `str.isdigit()`; it'll be true only for values representing integers:

```
try:
    d[t.tag] = int(text) if text.isdigit() else float(text)
except ValueError:
    d[t.tag] = text.encode('ASCII')
```

You can encapsulate this in a function, then use that function as in a list comprehension with dictionary comprehension combo:

```
def convert(v):
    try:
        return int(v) if v.isdigit() else float(v)
    except ValueError:
        return v.encode('ASCII')

uquotes = [{k: convert(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in json.loads(status.text[3:])]
```

Comment: Should have been more clear with my question. Where do I iterate over the dict to do the type conversion. Where does the try - except part go? Looked at the loads() object handler but could not find a way to make that work. Thank you!